# what is a regular file on unix

Tags: file, unix, manpage

I saw the man page of [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html).

where the below is mentioned.

```
-e  pathname
    True if pathname resolves to a file that exists. False if pathname cannot be resolved.
-f  pathname
    True if pathname resolves to a file that exists and is a regular file. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to a file that exists but is not a regular file.
```

the `-f` flag says 
*True if pathname resolves to a file that exists and is a regular file*
Could anybody please tell what is a regular file and what is not a regular file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Non-regular files are devices, pipes, sockets... try `[ -f /dev/tty0 ]`, for example. Symlinks are also non-regular, but they're *resolved* by `test -f`.

Answer (score 10):

They're text or binary data, called 'regular files' to distinguish them from other types like directories, symbolic links, sockets etc.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types

Answer (score 3):

It is not a directory, device file, block device, FIFO or socket. If you do an ls -l. The ones which start with a "-" are the files. Actually what most people to refer as just a file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont pretend to give an excellent explanation, just try to give some flavour.

I would say its better to understand what "regular" file is via its purpose. I'll try to define it: The purpose of regular file is to store  some information that can be used by some userspace program. Regular file is backend storage for some userspace program. That is text editors, image viewers, mp3 players, video players read from  regular files
and write to regular files.

Non regular files serve completely different purposes.
For instance block type file or character type file are the gateway
between userspace program and physical device (via kernel).

Named pipe file is a method for communication between two separate processes (IPC).

Socket file is a communication gateway between a process
working in this computer and process working on another computer. (via kernel, NIC and etc)

Symlink file usually is a pointer in the directory A to some file or directory in the directory B.

So regular file is a storage of bytes for some user program
like mp3 player, text editor, video player. When we want to read a book we open regular file via text editor. While non regular file usually is a gateway for communication between processes, or between userspace program and some physical device.

I would say regular file is like a truck full of books. While non regular file is like a  phone call via cell phone. The truck actually has books inside. While cell phone has nothing inside. I mean when you hear the voice of your friend it doesnt mean the friend is actually contained inside the cell phone. There is nothing inside cell phone. It just commincates with someone somewhere. If you disassemble cell phone you dont find the friend inside. However if you dissasemble the truck you ll find real books inside.

Regular file is like a box with dollar bills. While non regular file is like credit card or pay check.